# Laravel 5.8 local query scope with pivot table, return the related models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot, laravel-5.8

I have `Services` that have a many-to-many relationship to `People` as contacts, connected by a `services_contacts` pivot table and I'm attempting to create a local scope query on the `Service` model to return the primaryContacts():

```
public function scopePrimaryContacts($query)
{
    $pivot = $this->contacts()->getTable();

    return $query->whereHas('contacts', function ($q) use ($pivot) {
        return $q->where("{$pivot}.is_primary", true);
    });
}
```

This returns the services, where I need it to return the people that are related as `is_primary` on the pivot table itself. I'd like to be able to call `$this->primaryContacts` on my `Service` model, like I can call `$this->contacts` to get any/all contacts. Any ideas where to go from here? Here are the relationships... `contacts` on the `Service` model:

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class, 'services_contacts', 'service_uuid', 'person_uuid')
        ->withPivot('is_primary', 'is_active', 'contact_type_uuid')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

And `services` on the `Person` model:

```
public function services()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class, 'services_contacts', 'person_uuid', 'service_uuid');
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relationship method of both models please

Comment: They are both `belongsToMany`, but I'll add above.

Comment: What model is this scope going to be on as well?

Comment: It could go either way really, though that scope above is on the Service model. I also need to update all `services_contacts` that have is_primary, so I can ensure only have one primary contact for a service at a time (first things first though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't make this a scope, I'd make a second relationship function but with some additional params.

### Service Model

```
public function primaryContact() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class, 'services_contacts', 'service_uuid', 'person_uuid')
            ->wherePivot('is_primary', true)
            ->wherePivot('is_active', true);
}
```

Comment: I thought about that, but was stubborly trying to use a scope. This seems reasonable though. Thanks!

Comment: If you wanna go the scope route, I think defining a custom intermediate model would be the place to do it. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models. I've never done this myself though, so I'm not sure if it'd word

Comment: While we are here, can you think of a good way to then `detach()` all of these `primaryContacts`, without having to do a pluck and foreach situation?

Comment: I think that's your best bet honestly. Iterate and re `sync()` the relationships how you want them